# File not found when attempting to run a scheduled task in windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, script, scheduled-tasks

I am attempting to write a powershell script that schedules another powershell script. Here is the code that I currently have:

```
    $Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'pwsh.exe' -Argument '-NonInteractive -NoLogo -NoProfile -File "C:\test.ps1"'
    $Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 6pm
    $Settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet
    $Task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $Action -Trigger $Trigger -Settings $Settings
    Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Test" -InputObject $Task
```

This creates the task that I want, but when it is triggered, it fails, and claims that the file was not found. I would also like for it to prompt the user for the administrators password, but I could not figure that out in the documentation. I settled for non interactive, but that isn't really what I want. Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: the error code is 0x80070002

Comment: specify a location for pwsh.exe  maybe something like '%windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0'   You need to find it on your system and specify it's location or add it in the PATH

Comment: what is the EXACT, full text of the error? which file is not being found? _please add that info to your Question, not as a Comment_. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I have made the edit

Comment: Always use full paths. If you want a prompt run a shortcut with Run As Admin instead.

Comment: @hufflegamer123 - thank you for the added info. [*grin*] does the PoSh script generate any errors? you can add `Start-Transcript` to the beginning of your script.